# QT GET Request Response different from the one you get from an ordinary browser

Tags: facebook, qt, http, get, fql.multiquery

I'm trying to run a multiquery using the QT framework.
My query looks like this

```
{"query1":"SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()","query2":"SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid in(SELECT uid2 FROM #query1)"}
```

Until now I've discovered that if won't use the "#query1" method it will work. But I need it in my application since my actual query is more complex.

If I paste

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.multiquery?format=json&queries=%7B%22query1%22%3A%22SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%3Dme%28%29%22%2C%22query2%22%3A%22SELECT%20uid%2C%20name%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20in%28SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20%23query1%29%22%7D&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

inside a brower's adress bar where the access_token is a valid one I get my responce.

When  I make the same request from QT I get an empty json list ( "[ ]" )

Here is the QT code:

```
//this is just a markup, the read deal works

QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
QNetworkRequest request;

url="https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.multiquery?format=json&queries=%7B%22query1%22%3A%22SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%3Dme%28%29%22%2C%22query2%22%3A%22SELECT%20uid%2C%20name%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20in%28SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20%23query1%29%22%7D&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxx";

request.setRawHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

request.setUrl(url);

reply=manager->get(request);
connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
             this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));


void replyFinished(QNetworkReply *r){

qDebug()<<r->readAll();

}
```

This currently outputs "[ ]".
If I use a simple url like

> http://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=xxxxxxxxx

it works just fine.

- So what am I missing?
- Is it because there is a difference between my browser's get request 
  and my QT get request?
- Do I have to configure the header of my HTTP get request? And what
  values if so?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Perhaps one of the special characters (`&`=%26, `=`=%3D and `?`=%3F) are causing you an issue? For reference you can find all the special characters [here](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm#What-characters-need-to-be-encoded-and-why)

Comment: as I said I don't get any errors. As I gone deep in researching I think that the problem is that I have to cache the network reply.

Comment: Also worth noting that you are attempting to make an SSL connection without setting an SSL configuration. Try `request.setSslConfiguration(QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration());`

Answer (score 0):

The URL is already encoded, you should use `QUrl::setEncodedUrl()` to set it, or let `QUrl` encode it for you:

```
url = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.multiquery?format=json&queries={\"query1\":\"SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()\",\"query2\":\"SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid in(SELECT uid2 FROM #query1)\"}&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
```

Comment: Indeed. I used `QUrl::toProcentEncoded` to encode my query but it seems it does not affect spaces even if i add `QUrl::StrictMode`

Still after correcting this I realized that is still didn't work. So my research had finally paid off.
`request.setRawHeader("Accept-Encoding","Identity");` adding this will make your network reply to be downloaded.